# Branch.io has return empty referral parameters when my custom module (SDK) is in background state

Tags: android, background-process, deep-linking, branch.io, deeplink

I Have an issue regarding branch referral parameters are not getting while my app on background state.

I Integrated Branch using official Document.
My Intent Filters are kept inside opening Activity. i.e (Main Activity)
I kept singleTask mode for that Activity.

Issue 1:

I am  Designing Custom module SDK for Another app.So i integrated branch in my App level. I shared link in facebook. when i click on facebook link and my app is in background. Branch redirect to my App but i am not getting refferal parameters.Branch returns empty body.I Checked isAutoDeeplink also it showing false, Even I click Link on Facebook.

When My App is killed manually at that time branch returns referral parameters.I followed below link to integrate branch

https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/tree/master/Branch-SDK-TestBed

Can any one help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you have implemented two things within your app:

1. You have overridden the `onNewIntent()` method in the MainActivity:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       this.setIntent(intent);
   }
   ```
2. You are initializing the Branch SDK in the `onStart()` method and not the `onCreate()` method of your MainActivity.

Comment: thanks for responce, I initialized Branch in onStart() method only and i overridden onNewIntent() method also. but still its not working.

Comment: Can you write into `integrations@branch.io` so the Branch team can work with you directly and help you resolve the issue?